Running XRDP on official 390.157 NVIDIA drivers
I have a server with NVIDIA Quadro P2000 GPU, the latest version of NVIDIA drivers I can use is 390.157. I'm trying to get XRDP running on this server. My desktop enviroment is Gnome, as I failed getting any other DM running on this setup. So far I have been pretty much unsuccessful in the most part and I got stuck on this error, which I didn't manage to solve.
I can log in, but after that, the DM doesn't start and X11 session crashes with the following message:
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0x5
  Serial number of failed request:  6
  Current serial number in output stream:  8

